# Kivy pygame error

Tags: pygame, python-3.3, kivy

I've been trying to get Kivy to work on my Mac (Lion), but I've been encountering issues. I followed the instructions on the Kivy site, and since Kivy 1.8 supports Python 3, I wanted to run it with 3.3, and I finally got that to work, by editing the kivy file to point to 3.3 instead of 2.7. I tried drop a .py program on the Kivy icon, the app opened but nothing happened. So I tried to run it from the command line. It opened 3.3, as expected, but I got the following error.

```
Python 3.3.4 (default, Mar  6 2014, 20:14:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/sitepackages/pygame/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/sitepackages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
Referenced from: /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/sitepackages/pygame/base.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/lib/sitepackages/pygame/base.so
```

I have no idea why I would get this error, since I previously installed pygame for 3.3, and `import pygame` or `from pygame.base import *` work error free. Would this issue with pygame explain why .py files fail to execute when I drop them onto the Kivy icon?

Comment: How did you install python3? I guess there is maybe some build mix up between this and the system python.

Comment: As I remember, I got 3.3 through homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy.app and all the dependencies included in it is compiled with and for Python 2.7. You cannot use it for 3.3.

If you want to try Kivy with 3.3, you also need to compile Kivy yourself :)

Comment: But I can import kivy in 3.3 with no issues. The issue occurs when I try to drop a .py onto the Kivy icon or try to run a .py via Kivy from command line.

Comment: I wonder how you have been able to "drop" on the Kivy icon. Did you redo the whole Kivy.app package?

Comment: Send your new error with Python 3.3 and your own compiled Kivy then :)

Comment: Suppose I have a program that uses kivy called showcase.py. From Kivy's site, they say that I could run a Kivy application by dropping the application's file onto the Kivy.app icon. Yet when I try this, or loading a .kv file, Kivy.app opens up, but nothing else happens. However, if I go into Idle and run showcase.py, then everything runs without error. From the looks of things, the errors from running a .py via kivy from the command line are errors caused by running Python 2.7 code in 3.3, such as syntax errors fixed by adding parenthesis.